# Is it safe to upgrade to Windows 11 on a dual boot computer?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-11-upgrade

The title basically says it all.

I have a dual boot computer with:

1. Windows 10
2. Ubuntu 18.04

I've now received an invitation for a free upgrade to Windows 11, and I am wondering if the upgrade could interfere with the dual boot and potentially trigger issues.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you've done Windows 10 feature updates then it's safe to do the Windows 11 update.

Comment: @Mokubai means if you have installed feature updates for Windows 10.  However, I caution that the system requirements for Windows 11, are significantly different compared to Windows 10.  Secure Boot might not be compatible with your current configuration, especially, if you been using Legacy boot mode instead of UEFI. Ubuntu 18.04 has some age on it which tells me it’s potentially an older install making the Legacy boot mode a higher probability

Comment: Basically if it is offering you the Windows 11 update through Windows Update, the same as Windows 10 updates, then you should be good to go. If you are manually updating or it is saying that you have to change settings to do the update then that is when problems may occur.

Comment: @Mokubai I am indeed receiving the Windows 11 update via the usual Windows update notifications.

Comment: @Ramhound, the boot mode is UEFI, with GNU Grub 2.04

Comment: It sounds like your machine should seamlessly upgrade to Windows 11.  As always with any major upgrade you should backup your important files.

Answer (score 0):

I have a laptop that came with Windows 10 pre-installed. Since then, I have installed Fedora as dual boot on it, and I am using GRUB to select which operating system to start on startup. Yesterday, I updated Windows 10 to 11 using Windows update. It worked great without any issues, and I have not had to do any changes in BIOS/UEFI regarding Secure Boot or so.

Here is another thread on Ask Ubuntu about this question: [Will updating my Windows 10 to Windows 11 affect my Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346846/will-updating-my-windows-10-to-windows-11-affect-my-ubuntu). Perhaps if Secure Boot isn't already enabled, you might need to enable it before updating and then disable it again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

With a Legacy/CSM boot (thus, not UEFI based) there is a very high probability (99.999%) Windows will overwrite the grub bootloader with its own bootloader.
In which case you need to boot from a Linux live-USB and re-install grub, which can be complicated.

On UEFI systems (with or without Secure Boot) both bootloaders exist side-by side in the EFI partition and in general you can update either OS without affecting the other OS at all.

Still... **Play it safe**: Backup your important stuff before you start!